# Can't fetch the image in another php file to display on the current php file

Tags: php, fetch

I'm new to PHP and I am creating a program where in a user can add a profile and add a profile picture. However, if I am to update the profile of the user and also change the profile picture, I am getting an error saying:

> Warning: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms_aries\admin\includes\admin_navigation.php on line 27
>
> Warning: mysqli_error(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms_aries\admin\includes\admin_navigation.php on line 30
>   Error loading profile picture

Here is the code of the profile.php:

```
<?php
    include "includes/admin_header.php";
?>

<?php

    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){

        $username = $_SESSION['username'];

        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = '{$username}' ";

        $select_user_profile_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_user_profile_query)){
            $user_name = $row['user_name'];
            $user_firstname = $row['user_firstname'];
            $user_lastname = $row['user_lastname'];
            $user_email = $row['user_email'];
            $user_image = $row['user_image'];
            $user_password = $row['user_password'];
        }
    }
?>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['edit_user'])){

        $the_user_firstname = escape($_POST['user_firstname']);
        $the_user_lastname = escape($_POST['user_lastname']);
        $the_user_email = escape($_POST['user_email']);
        //Profile Images
        $the_user_temp_image = $_FILES['user_image']['name'];
        $the_user_image = $_FILES['user_image']['name'];

        $the_user_name = escape($_POST['user_name']);
        $the_user_password = escape($_POST['user_password']);

        move_uploaded_file($the_user_temp_image, "../images/$the_user_image");

        $query = "UPDATE users SET ";
        $query .= "user_firstname = '{$the_user_firstname}', ";
        $query .= "user_lastname = '{$the_user_lastname}', ";
        $query .= "user_email = '{$the_user_email}', ";
        $query .= "user_image = '{$the_user_image}', ";
        $query .= "user_password = '{$the_user_password}' ";
        $query .= "WHERE user_name = '{$the_user_name}' ";

        $update_user = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

        confirm($update_user);

        mysqli_close($connection);
        }
?>
```

And here is the code of the admin_navigation.php where in I am getting the error message:

```
<?php 
                        if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
                            $username = $_SESSION['username'];

                            $query = "SELECT user_image FROM users WHERE user_name = '{$username}'";
                            $select_profile_picture = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

                            if (!$select_profile_picture) {
                                die('Error loading profile picture'.mysqli_error($connection));
                            }
                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_profile_picture)) {
                                $profile_picture = $row['user_image'];
                            }
                        }
                     ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Careless me. I just need to change the `$the_user_temp_image = $_FILES['user_image']['name']` to `$the_user_temp_image = $_FILES['user_image]['tmp_name']` in order to fetched the temporary images. I also try to remove the `mysqli_close($connection)` in order to remove the error and fetched the values of the page because I realized that when I am closing the connection, PHP automatically vanishes the `$connection` variable and automatically closes the connection behind the scenes when it fits to do that.